# If the hypotenuse is $4$ times the height from $A$, prove that one of the angles is $15^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

In a right triangle (with $\angle CAB = 90^\circ$), suppose $|BC| = 4|AD|$ with $AD$ being the height from $A$ to $BC$. Prove that $\angle BCA$ is $15^\circ$.

I had a similar problem but with $22.5^\circ$. I thought it would be similar, but I found nothing I could do. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that: by the Pitagoras Theorem $(\overline{CA})^2+(\overline{AB})^2=(\overline{BC})^2$, and by the area of triangle $\frac{(\overline{BC})^2}{4}=(\overline{CA})\cdot(\overline{AB})$

Now  if $\measuredangle BCA=\alpha$ then:
$$(\sin{\alpha}+\cos{\alpha})^2=\left(\frac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{BC}}+\frac{\overline{AC}}{\overline{BC}}\right)^2$$
then:
$$1+\sin{2\alpha}=\frac{3}{2}$$
then
$$2\alpha=30^{\circ}\Longrightarrow \alpha=15^{\circ}$$

Comment: Thanks! It sure is what I was looking for!

Comment: Is more easy $\sin{2\alpha}=2\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}=2\frac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{BC}}\cdot\frac{\overline{AC}}{\overline{BC}}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  If $\alpha=\angle BCA$ then looking at the similar triangles $\triangle ABC,\,\triangle DAC,\,\triangle DBA$ gives
$$\tan\alpha+\cot\alpha=4\ ,$$
which can be solved by using standard trig formulae.  See if you can fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We have $$a^2+b^2=c^2 $$
and (calculate area in two different ways)
$$ ab=\frac{c^2}{4}. $$

So: $$a^2+b^2=4ab$$
Dividing by $ab$ both sides and setting $x=\frac{a}{b}$, this gives us:
$$ x+\frac{1}{x}=4.$$

Once we have $x$, that is we have $\frac{a}{b}$, invert the relevant trigonometric function to get the needed angle.

Comment: Thanks, I have to prove afterwards the tangent of 15°, guess I can solve the problem doing it backwards. Would there be a solution in that matter? Getting first the angle, then the tangent.